# Restart python scipy.solve_ivp integrator with new parameters after terminal event occurs

Tags: python, scipy, ode

I'm using scipy.integrate.solve_ivp to solve a system of ODEs because it has the event functions.

The reason why I need this function is that during the integration sometimes I get a singular matrix, and everytime that happens I need to finish the integration and restart it with new parameters.

I would like to know if is possible to restart the scipy.integrate.solve_ivp with new parameters after a terminal event has occurred, and if so how could I do it.

Any help would be very much appreciated.

This is my current script based on an example from 
https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.integrate.solve_ivp.html:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import numpy as np
from scipy.integrate import solve_ivp
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation
from animate_plot import animate

def upward_cannon(t, y):
    return [y[1], -0.5]

def hit_ground(t, y):
    return y[0]

def apex(t,y):
    return y[1]

hit_ground.terminal = True
hit_ground.direction = -1

t0 = 0

tf = 10

sol = solve_ivp(upward_cannon, t_span=[t0, tf], y0=[90, 10], t_eval=np.arange(t0,tf, 0.01), events=[hit_ground,apex],
                dense_output=True)

linesData = { 1: [[-0.0, 0.0],[0.0, 0.0]]}#,
            # 2: [[-0.5, 0],[0.5, 0.0]]}#, 3: [[-0.5, 0],[0.5, 0]]}

pointsofInterest = {}#3: [[0.5, 0.0]]}#, 2: [[180.0, 10]]}

model_markers = np.array([])

plot_title = 'Upward Particle'
plot_legend = ['Forward Dynamics']

q_rep = sol.y.T[:,0]

fig = plt.figure()

ax = fig.add_subplot(111)

xs = np.arange(t0, tf, 0.01)

for idx in range(0,q_rep.shape[0]):   #looping statement;declare the total number of frames
    y=q_rep[idx]       # traveling Sine wave
    ax.cla()
    ax.scatter(xs[idx],y, s=50)
    plt.ylim([-10, 190])
    plt.xlim([-100, 100])
    plt.pause(0.001)
plt.show()
```

Thank you in advance.

Kind Regards

Answer (score -1):

You have two options, both are `recursive`.

Option 1: Write the function to call itself inside of the script. This would be true `recursion` and elegant.

Option 2: If your function comes across these values you need to resolve, use `argparsing` and `os` to call the function with specified values.

Example:

```
os.system(python3 filename.py -f argparseinputs)
```